# Text Length equal to checking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Got a simple question. I got a text field that gets updated and filled with character I want to perform actions when they have a length. for example when the length is 12 (12 character) I want it to do something and when the length is 24, etc.

Can I just do:

```
if (textfield.text.length == 12){
//do something
}
```

hope someone can help me out :)

thanks

Comment: @thelaws that is a totally inane comment. Try WHAT out? Obviously whether you try it out or not, an `if` in the middle of nowhere will do nothing.

Comment: If you are just wanting to check this at a certain point in your code, then yes.  You can check it like you show.  Note that it is typically written like `if ([textfield.text length] == 12) {` though since length is a method.  (Either one will work though.)  If you want something to happen **in response** to the textfield **becoming** 12 characters, then use the technique in the answers below.

Comment: @Yar his question is whether that if statement will work as he describes, it seemed to me that he knew where to get the updates.

Comment: thanks guys I was not looking for a update before but When I made it work, I was. So everyone really helped me out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the delegate

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

and use the if you have created yourself inside it like

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textfield.text.length == 12){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement there will work, with the one consideration that it's being applied to the text field as it was before the the current character is added to it (assuming the `replacementString` is one character).

Answer (score 2):

Set up a `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method. Calculate what the text field will contain once `replacementString` is applied and do what you need to if it matches what you're looking for.

Note that this also gets called for delete and paste events.

Comment: +1 for not checking the length of the text before the replacement happens. For future readers: the "formula" to calculate the text length after the replacement goes like this: `NSInteger textLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;`

Answer (score 1):

Write Down This code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    if (textfield.text.length == 12)
       {
           condition......
       }
    else if (textfield.text.length == 24)
       {
           condition......
       }
    else
       {
           condition......
       }
}
```