# how to check that if text fileds values and show alert and empty the textfield in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am entering value textfiled i want that if it is correct value then its ok other wise show alert and make the textfield empty.So that user may enter correct value i have tried many ways but i am not getting it solved.

```
  -(void)textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:(UITextField*)tf{

   NSString*test=clinicMarkupTextField.text;



if([test isEqualToString:@"1"]){
    NSString*value=@"1";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}

else if([test isEqualToString:@"1.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"1.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}


else if([test isEqualToString:@"2"]){

    NSString*value=@"2";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}


else if([test isEqualToString:@"2.5"]){

    NSString*value=@"2.5";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}


else if([test isEqualToString:@"3"]){

    NSString*value=@"3";

    appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;


}

else if([test length] >=3 || [test floatValue] > 3 || [test floatValue] <1 )  {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Clinic Markup can only be 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and 3 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

     }
  }
```

Comment: When are you running this code?

Comment: I am runing this code in textDidChange method of textfield becuase i want to get input only the desired inputs which are in shown above

Comment: u should check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775023/text-length-equal-to-checking/10775085#10775085)

Comment: @Filoo can you please edit in my code how to do this please if you can

Comment: @Alexander i have edited my question see where i am using this code

Comment: There is no `textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup` UITextField delegate method, remove the `ClinicMarkup` part.

Comment: If the textfield can only have 5 values why don't you replace the textField with a UISegmentedControl? And your logic is flawed too. "2.4" won't raise an alert but is not a valid input.

Comment: then where to add this clinicalMarkup i am calling this method in viewDidLoad method like this   [clinicMarkupTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeClinicMarkup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

Comment: @MatthiasBauch i have to do using textfield only becuase it is requirement is there anyway to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

For this particular problem, I would use a `UIStepper` controll instead:

```
stepper.minimumValue = 1.0f;
stepper.maximumValue = 3.0f;
stepper.stepValue = 0.5f;
```

A stepper control looks like this:
 [image]

Comment: nice idea, that could be the best method to proceed

Answer (score 2):

@james If you have only a single text field , then you can implement this code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
 NSString *strText=textField.text;
    if ([strText isEqualToString:@"1"]||[strText isEqualToString:@"1.5"]||[strText isEqualToString:@"2"]||[strText isEqualToString:@"2.5"]||[strText isEqualToString:@"3"]) 
    {
        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=strText;
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Clinic Markup can only be 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and 3 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
return YES;
}
```

Comment: what if may i dont use -(BOOL) and use method as i have done like that will it work

Comment: the method i have posted is the delegate , and it will be called when the return button is clicked for an text field , and the method you have posted , for that i need to know where are you calling that method

Comment: it is working fine but i need to empty the text box in else statement when i write that statement then app crashes

Comment: @james what are you writing in the else block, please post the line of code

Comment: @james   textField.text = @"";
is this the line you have posted?

Comment: You can replace the else block by this code
    else{
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Clinic Markup can only be 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and 3 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
textField.text = @"";
    }

Comment: but i have to empty the text box in else statement where to write that code

Comment: please check carefully i have written that code below the line [alert release]; , thats where you want the text field to be empty.

Comment: yes i have tried but application crashes and Say EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i write this line for empty the textbox

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11926/discussion-between-developersaremad-and-james)

Answer (score 0):

Setup your delegate

```
clinicMarkupTextField.delegate = self;
clinicMarkupTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

and try the below code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if(clinicMarkupTextField == textField) //only if u have more then 1 text field
    {
        NSString*test=textField.text;

    if([test isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            NSString*value=@"1";
        appDelegate.clinicalMarkup=value;
     }

         ---SNIP---             

        else if([test length] >=3 || [test floatValue] > 3 || [test floatValue] <1 )  {

         //if all condition fails 
         textField.text = @"";

             UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Clinic Markup can only be 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and 3 " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
             [alert release];

          }
       }
 return yes;

    }
```

Comment: my code method is also same i am applying only on one textfield so my code why is not working

Comment: my idea is just to clear the textbox contents on alertview show simple